# Appending a JSON file from JS file in Express Application

Tags: node.js, json, express

This is a learning struggle, and I might just be approaching this from an awkward angle, but guidance is appreciated. This project is using just HTML, Node, and Express.

I have a small app that is supposed to take survey inputs to build a 'friend' profile (essentially only a name, imgURL, and 7 question answers each a value 1-5). I want to save all the Friend objects with those properties in a JSON file in a `data` sub-directory so that as new users are added, I can compare the friend objects against one another.

On my front end, I want to step through each stage one bootstrap card at a time, so I have a `questions.js` file that manipulates the DOM to start with the name and imgURL and create a new 'Friend' object, then go one question at a time (printing question text from an array of strings) and capturing radio button selections (values 1-5) `on("submit")`. End result is I have iterated through all the questions, grabbed the submitted values, and pushed them to a 'scores' array within the friend object, resulting thusly:

```
{
    "name": "Ahmed",
    "photo": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/6/005/064/1bd/3435aa3.jpg",
    "scores": [5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1]
  }
```

All of this works nicely, and I end up with good User navigation through the questions and a new Friend object with all my desired data persisting in the linked JS file.

Now how the ding-dang do I push that new Friend object as an array item in my `friends.json` file? I kind of get that I need maybe an Ajax call within the `questions.js`, or maybe I'm off-base and this belongs within an `app.post` route in my `server.js`, but so far my research and trials have only served up more confusion.

This might be a wack question, but I think there is a best practice in there I need to learn. Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Doing a POST request using the Fetch API

As you have mentioned, you need a `POST` route in your server to handle that.

Your frontend should do an AJAX POST call to that endpoint with that newly created object. You can use the [Featch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to do that:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/friends', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "Ahmed",
        photo: "https://media.licdn.com/.../foo.jpg",
        scores: [5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1],
    }),
});
```

#### Modify the data on the backend

Then, assuming this is just a simple learning example, on your backend you have two options:

- Have that `friends.json` file already loaded in memory as an array and just push a new element to it.
- Load, parse and save `friends.json` on every request.

If this is meant to be a production server, then you might consider using REDIS, MongoDB or any other database that fits your needs.

Here you can see both of them:

```
// This will be loaded and parsed already (only used in option 1):
const friends = require("../data/friends.json");

// Only used in option 2:
const fs = require('fs');

// Tell the server to parse JSON bodies in your requests:
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Support JSON-encoded bodies.

// Get existing friends:
app.post('/api/friends', function(req, res, next) {
    // Option 1, persisted in memory:
    res.json(friends);

    // Option 2, loaded and saved everytime:
    try {
        res.json(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../data/friends.json")));
    } catch(err) {
        // JSON.parse might fail:
        next(err);
    }
});

// Create new friend:
app.post('/api/friends', function(req, res, next) {
    // Option 1, persisted in memory:
    friends.push(req.body); // This should be validated properly!
    res.json(friends);

    // Option 2, loaded and saved everytime:
    try {
        const friends = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../data/friends.json"));
        friends.push(req.body); // This should be validated properly!
        fs.writeFileSync("../data/friends.json", JSON.stringify(friends));
        res.json(friends);
    } catch(err) {
        // JSON.parse or fs.writeFileSync might fail:
        next(err);
    }
});
```

#### ✨ Recommended way to use body-parser

As an additional suggestion, even though you will see `body-parser` being used as `app.use(bodyParser.json())` in a lot of resources out there, [the recommended way to use it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#express-route-specific) is to add it only to the route it is relevant for:

> **Express route-specific**
>
> This example demonstrates adding body parsers specifically to the routes that need them. In general, this is the most recommended way to use body-parser with Express.

So, in your case you would do:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

...

app.post('/api/friends', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the robust answer! I will work with this and return if I have any questions or issues. Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added `body-parser`? Are you sending the right `Content-Type` header? You can try doing a `POST` with Postman to make sure the problem is not on your frontend. Maybe this other question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts

Comment: @KevinHyde You have deleted the previous comment right? I was going crazy thinking I wrote it in the wrong tab 

Comment: Yep, I just now saw my issue . . . . middleware from your example was set with `app.use(bodyParser.json());` and my routing file was configured using `var router = express.Router();`.  Swapped `app.` for `router.` and I am back in business! Thanks again.